# VSCode syntax highlighting breaks when declaring a nullable variable in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, blazor-webassembly, omnisharp

I'm developing in Blazor and am running into an issue with nullable variables and VSCode. When trying to create razor component parameters and make them nullable, all lines below in VSCode stop showing correct C# syntax highlighting.

[image: gif showing the syntax highlighting issue]

People having similar issues have suggested setting the following in settings.json in VSCode:

```
"editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,
"csharp.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true
```

but this doesn't appear to fix the problem for me.
I'm using the latest version of C#/Omnisharp for VSCode.

Relevant part of the code is as follows: (though it might not be that useful)

```
@code{
    private bool isChecked = false;

    [Parameter] public int? area { get; set; } 
    [Parameter] public double? val { get; set; } 
    [Parameter] public double dist { get; set; } 

    private void toggleChecked()
    {
        isChecked = !isChecked;
    }
}
```

Is there any known way to fix this or should I be declaring nullable variables some other way perhaps?

Comment: Maybe you need to define nullable in your csproj file  **<Nullable>enable</Nullable>**

Comment: If you close and reopen the file, does it work correctly again?

Comment: @Barış Can Yılmaz
Nullable is enabled

Comment: @Caius Jard
It does not. I've restarted and reopened after setting the settings in VSCode.

Comment: What if you use `Nullable<int>` instead? It should be the same as `int?` is just syntactic sugar.

Comment: This seems to have to do with Razors `@` code blocks. Found some post, non of them really worth linking here though, since they are unanswered/open like this one ... I don't have those issues with 'plain' c# and current c#/omnisharp extensions.