# Blazor component code syntax background color in Visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, blazor

There is a problem with the colors inside a Blazor component in visual studio code.
Only the first property access modifier gets highlighted as you can see on the screenshot.

[image]

I wonder if that there is a way to fix this?

Comment: Use the TextMate Scope inspector to determine why a token has that color

Comment: I think this is caused by the nullable properties of your component. [See my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71923624/vscode-syntax-highlighting-breaks-when-declaring-a-nullable-variable-in-c-sharp) about this. I don't think theres a fix out yet.